# How to resize 3d model in wpf?

Tags: wpf

I have a human face 3d model,and I want to resize for example:eyes or nose or mouth,etc.
But my human face 3d model is "one object"

how can I resize eyes,etc.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to manipulate the data within your object - if thats not possible you cannot resize individual items.

You can always resize the whole thing using a different scale but resizing individual items requires individual scale factors which in turn means accessing individual objects - I don't think there is any way around that :-(

PS. Can you post a small version of your objects - for example - a collection of squared boxes - this should be helpful to suggest ways for scaling individual objects if you could manipuate them.

Comment: I am a begineer in WPF.
I just use the following code to load human face 3d model:

Model3DGroup MyModel = CurrentHelixObjReader.Read(@".\objFile\FaceTS_OBJ.obj");

and display them:
model.Content = MyModel;

change color:
System.Windows.Media.Media3D.Material mat = MaterialHelper.CreateMaterial(new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(248, 197, 183)));

and resize whole model:
var group = MyModel as Model3DGroup;
foreach (var el in group.Children){
var t = el as GeometryModel3D;
t.Transform = new ScaleTransform3D(20, 20,20);
t.Material = mat;
t.BackMaterial = mat;
}

Comment: Is it really no way to resize individual items?
I have to use code to resize eyes or nose.